# Generated libtool is removing *.gcno on linking when compiling PHP extension

Tags: php, code-coverage, php-extension, libtool, gcov

I want to have code coverage for my PHP extension. I am using the following setup:

```
PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2018 20:43:46) ( NTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I can build the extension without any issues and run all tests.
I am configuring the extension as follows:

```
CXX=gcc CFLAGS="--coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage $CFLAGS" LDFLAGS="--coverage" ./configure
```

The compilation step of `make all`

```
/bin/bash /home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/libtool --mode=compile cc -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/include -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/main -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O0   -c /home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/zookeeper.c -o zookeeper.lo
```

generates the following files:

```
.libs/zookeeper.gcno
.libs/zookeeper.o
```

Now the linking part:

```
/bin/bash /home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/include -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/main -I/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O0  --coverage -o zookeeper.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/modules  zookeeper.lo -Wl,-rpath,/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/target/release -L/home/alex/Projects/php-7.2.2/ext/zookeeper/target/release -lzookeeper_bridge
```

logs the following step:

```
rm -fr  .libs/zookeeper.gcno
```

I managed to narrow it down to the following line of `ltmain.sh` script that is bundled with PHP:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d1186b8/ltmain.sh#L3457

My `libtool` generated during `./configure` also has this line:

```
*.$objext)
```

Now if I manually change it to:

```
*.$objext | *.gcno)
```

the linking process no longer removes the `.gcno` file and I can get correct coverage report.

I assume there is a way to force the linking process to not to remove the `.gcno` files and therefore allow me to generate the proper coverage report. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume there is a way to force the linking process to not to remove the .gcno files and therefore allow me to generate the proper coverage report.

In this case, probably not.  The `ltmain.sh` you referenced above says it's from libtool [1.5.26](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ltmain.sh#L46).  However, the version of libtool that claims to no longer remove .gcno profiler information is libtool [2.2.6](https://github.com/autotools-mirror/libtool/blob/master/NEWS#L447).  The fix is probably in later libtool versions as well.

So to fix it, you'll have to get the `php-src` maintainers to upgrade libtool.  Or patch `libtool` as part of your build process as you've done by hand.

Comment: I came up with a workaround: Right after `phpize` I call: `aclocal && libtoolize --copy --force && autoreconf`. Now I have the up to date libtools and coverage works fine. Though I am not sure if this won't cause issues I cannot foreseen yet :/

Comment: That approach could work as well, since code coverage seems to be your main concern.  But, as you said, there may be unforseen build issues doing this.